# Angular error : Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)

Tags: angular, angularjs-scope

I'm migrating a system from angular 2 to "angular 4" and I'm having an annoying problem for 2 days ... I've already fixed all the errors I was giving and etc ... But there is an error that is not letting me continue that is the "Can not resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)."

I do not have much knowledge about angular. If in case you are missing any information or file, I am here to add.

I'll put the changed codes where they generated the following error:
[image]

**Old** **Code**

> Main.ts

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { LocationStrategy,
         HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';


import { GlobalService } from './+frameworks/+foundation/global.service';

import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AuthGuard } from './+frameworks/+foundation/auth/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from './+frameworks/+foundation/auth/auth.service';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  },
  { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
  GlobalService,
  Title,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  AuthGuard,
  AuthService,
]);
```

> app.module.ts <<< did not exist
>
> app.components

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { HeaderbarComponent } from './+frameworks/+foundation/headerbar/headerbar.component';
import { MessageComponent } from './+frameworks/+foundation/message/message.component';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
               HeaderbarComponent,
               MessageComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  private viewContainerRef : ViewContainerRef;
  public constructor(viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
  }
}
```

---

**New** **Code**

> Main.ts

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { LocationStrategy,
         HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


import { GlobalService } from './+frameworks/+foundation/global.service';

import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

import { AuthGuard } from './+frameworks/+foundation/auth/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from './+frameworks/+foundation/auth/auth.service';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  },
  { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
  GlobalService,
  Title,
  HttpModule,
  AuthGuard,
  AuthService,
]);
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderbarComponent } from './+frameworks/+foundation/headerbar/headerbar.component';
import { MessageComponent } from './+frameworks/+foundation/message/message.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderbarComponent, MessageComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  private viewContainerRef : ViewContainerRef;
  public constructor(viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef) { container ref
    this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your setup looks quite different to the current state of the repo: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed. Why don't you use the `SharedModule`, which brings in the core Angular modules? Also FYI you can simplify your constructor using `constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }`.

Comment: "Your setup looks quite different to the current state of the repo: github.com/mgechev/angular-seed .". Would you help me out of this? I'm sorry if it seems ridiculous my doubt, but I do not have much knowledge on what to do in this code. And if you need more information from him, just ask.

Comment: The error message suggests you're using the above seed project. However, the code you've shown looks rather different to the code in the seed. So I'm wondering what you've changed and why or, if the changes have been made by the repo owner as part of their process of upgrading, if you've tried to apply the same changes to your app.

Comment: Okay, I'll update and put the old code together as I received, before attempting to migrate to angular4

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated the question with the old code and the new one

Comment: @user1875730 How do you provide value `useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'`? Is that somewhere in webpack?